# Select object using jQuery each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-audio

I am trying to set a variable to represent a unique audio object for each class as follows:

```
var x0 = new Audio('1.wav');
var x1 = new Audio('2.wav');

$('.class').each(function(i) {
    var x = "x" + i; 
    alert(x); 

    //...code that is identically executed for each class using different audio clips...
});
```

The above code results in an alert that displays the string "x1" rather than the object x1.

Is it possible to set a variable to equal an object using the method above (or a similar method)? I know that `var x = x1` properly sets the variable x to the object x1. Now I'm just looking for a way to accomplish that in a more dynamic/automatic way.

Comment: If your putting any numbering if you variable names then they should be an array. This way in `.each` you can simply refer to an index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setting distinct variables for each, I'd put them in an array.

```
var audioFiles = [
  new Audio('1.wav'),
  new Audio('2.wav')
];
```

Then, you can access them like so:

```
audioFiles[0]
```

or,

```
audioFiles[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = {
  0: new Audio('1.wav'),
  1: new Audio('2.wav')
}

$('.class').each(function(i) {
  var a = x[i];
  alert(a);
})
```

You may also use array instead of object if you are sure that you are going to use subsequent numbers as a keys and any number isn't going to be skipped for some reason.

Answer (score -1):

You should be pushing them into an array as you add them - then you can target the objects by array positon - and the .each will work as intended. Each will refer to the objects in the array - as opposed to an individual string value.

```
var audiofiles = [];
var x0 = new Audio('1.wav');
var x1 = new Audio('2.wav');
audiofiles.push(x0);
audiofiles.push(x1);

audiofiles.each(function(i) {
    alert(i); 
});
```